# What are the built-in @Provider classes in Resteasy?

Tags: resteasy

The documentation for the `resteasy.use.builtin.providers` configuration switch reads:

> Whether or not to register default, built-in @Provider classes.

I have set that to false to use my own (GWT) JSON format, but would like to know what i am missing or if is there anyone i should not exclude.

So, what are the built-in @Provider classes in Resteasy, or how can i find them?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know a documentation for that. Best way may be to search in [the sources](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy).

If you are only using resteasy-jaxrs you can find these providers in the master-branch:

```
* org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.mapper.ApacheHttpClient4ExceptionMapper
* org.jboss.resteasy.core.AcceptHeaderByFileSuffixFilter
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.AcceptEncodingGZIPFilter
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.AcceptEncodingGZIPInterceptor
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPEncodingInterceptor
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DataSourceProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DefaultTextPlain
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FileProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FormUrlEncodedProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.IIOImageProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.InputStreamProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.JaxrsFormProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.ReaderProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.SerializableProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.SourceProvider
* org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.StringTextStar
```

This are the classes annotated with `@Provider`. Mostly the same are registered in [META-INF/services/ javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers).

But I'm not sure why you want to do disable them. AFAIK if you register a `@Provider` which `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` or `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` the default one will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. The issue is that i have different media types per entity, such as application/vnd.kornell.v1.entity.person+json, don't know how that would works. To preserve the original providers i ended up disabling the json providers explicitly in jboss-deployment-structure.xml