# Resteasy 3 @Context HttpServletRequest always null

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy, undertow

We were using Resteasy 2 but we are upgrading to Resteasy 3 and the `HttpServletRequest` injection is always `null`.

Our modified security interceptor/filter that looks like:

```
@Provider
@ServerInterceptor
@Precedence("SECURITY")
public class SecurityInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        // Need access to "servletRequest" but it is always null

        if (!isTokenValid(pmContext, method)) {
            requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        // post processing
    }
}
```

And the application class looks like:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public RestApplication() {

        // Interceptors
        this.singletons.add(new SecurityInterceptor());

        // Services
        this.singletons.add(new MyService());
    }

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return this.empty;
    }

    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return this.singletons;
    }
}
```

Sample API:

```
@Path("/test")
public class MyService extends BaseService {

    @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

    @GET
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response hello() {

        // Need access to HttpServletRequest but it's null

        return Response.ok("hello").build();
    }
}
```

However, looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24351879/1877617) and [this](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/f454a87132fbcb3c413282105b87585f6f73bb40/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers) posts, I don't see `HttpServletRequest` injection provider.

This leads me to believe that I may need an additional plugin. This is what is installed:

```
jose-jwt
resteasy-atom-provider
resteasy-cdi
resteasy-crypto
resteasy-jackson2-provider
resteasy-jackson-provider
resteasy-jaxb-provider
resteasy-jaxrs
resteasy-jettison-provider
resteasy-jsapi
resteasy-json-p-provider
resteasy-multipart-provider
resteasy-spring
resteasy-validator-provider-11
resteasy-yaml-provider
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding them to the classes (instead of singletons) and let resteasy create them.

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for your response. Your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on **@peeskillet** suggestion, modifying to return new class instances instead of singletons resolved my issue.

Thus my modified `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` file looks like:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public RestApplication() {

        // Interceptors
        this.classes.add(SecurityInterceptor.class);

        // Services
        this.classes.add(MyService.class);
    }

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return this.classes;
    }

    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return this.singletons;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SecurityInterceptor's constructor to get these values:

```
///...
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private ServletContext context;

    public SecurityInterceptor(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context ServletContext context) {
       this.request = request;
       this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        // The "servletRequest" won't be null anymore
        if (!isTokenValid(pmContext, method)) {
            requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
        }
    }

 ///...
```

This'll solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I ended up going with the approach @peeskillet recommend as we would have to make changes in many places to accept the values in the constructor.

Comment: I'm happy helping. I didn't see the "new SecurityInterceptor()" , but it was a problem too.